# Opening several packages at once using a for loop

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me why this code gives the error `Error in library(packages[1]) : 'package' must be of length 1`

```
   packages <- c("googleVis","dplyr","ggvis","openintro","plotly","maps","RColorBrewer","mapproj","stargazer","swirl")

for (i in 1:length(packages)) {
    library(packages[i])
}
```

I just don't see it. It's a subsetted vector which should be a single character vector for library().

Note: I know that I can use lapply but this is for the sake of the error.

Thanks

Comment: library(packages[i], character.only = T)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Just by adding character.only=T as an argument to the library function.